# How to draw an empty points on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

the task is to draw an empty point on a scatterplot. I wrote the following code with output, but don't know what to do next? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2arGg.png)

```
#fig = plt.figure(facecolor='blue')
plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
plt.scatter(data[data.predict==3].X, data[data.predict==3].Y, c = data[data.predict==3].proba_final, cmap='jet')
plt.scatter(points['X'], points['Y'], c = y_vis_2, cmap='jet', edgecolors='w')
plt.title('Category 3', size=20)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
cbar.ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='#03045c'
#plt.fill(150, 150, "b") 
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 300])
ax.set_ylim([0, 300])
plt.xticks(range(0,350,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the points empty you need to use "facecolors" and "edgecolors" arguments instead of "c" argument. See example below:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
plt.scatter(x, y,facecolors="None", edgecolors='r', lw=1,alpha=0.5)
```